# How to send parameters to asp c# webMethod ? using Ajax Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
  //c# method
  [WebMethod]
     public static string HelloAction(string value)
     {
          Client clt = new Client();
          clt.name = "Hello "+value;

          return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clt);
     }
```

// Javascript code

```
var nameJson= {
         "name" : "William"
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'name': nameJson }), // ??
        url: "Index.aspx/HelloAction",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: successHello
    });
```

But chrome console show this error: POST http://localhost:9252/Index.aspx/HelloAction 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Do you have custom errors turned off? What is the stack looking like? How about routing? Have you setup route mapping anywhere?

Comment: The file path is fine, since invoking a method with no input parameters this returns me values ​​without problem, but when I want to send parameters to the method, there the system falls

Comment: You're going to have to expose the exceptions so we can see if it's a binding issue or what. I don't see any issue with your method.

Comment: Try stringifying this object: `{ name: nameJson }` instead of `{ 'name': nameJson }`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Actually just stringify. `nameJson` You're double wrapping like this as it stands: `{ 'name' : { 'name' : 'william' } }` which will not work out properly. Unless that's a typo. Didn't see that at first.

Comment: Ok, this is exception message: [link](https://paste2.org/W9NJy0Jw)

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax code change the following line

```
data: JSON.stringify({ 'name': nameJson })
```

to this one

```
 data: JSON.stringify(nameJson)
```